# Determination of Weights for Hierarchical Sparse Girds Quadrature

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab, quadrature

For the solving a $d$-dimensional SDE with a **sparse grid algorithm**  related to an option pricing problem I ended up having to solve the following integral equation.

$g_{\bar{l},\bar{i}} = \int_D p(e^{x_1},\dots, e^{x_d}) \varphi_{l_1,i_1}(x_1) \dots \varphi_{l_d,i_d}(x_d) d(x_1,\dots,x_d)$

Whereas

- $\bar{l} = (l_1, \dots, l_d)$ stands for the level of current
  refinement and $\bar{i} = (i_1, \dots, i_d)$ is a multi-index
  referring to the index of the grid point in the sparse grid. This
  yields that the tupel $(\bar{l},\bar{i})$ refers to grid point in the
  sparse grid.

The sparse grid has no boundary points and is constructed via the hierarchial basis approach. This means I already calculated the given grid points of the sparse grid. The are also the notes of my quadrature. My problem is that I do not know on how to choose proper weights for my quadrature.

**So basically my questions come down to:
Assuming the grid points of a sparse grids are given through a hierarchical basis approach, how am I suppose to choose the weights of a quadrature if we assume that the nodes of the quadrature are the given sparse grid points.**

---

Further information, but not relevant for solving the problem.

- function $p(..)$ is a given payoff
- the $\varphi_{l_k,i_k}$ refer the standard construction of sparse grids through the hierarchical basis. Namely speaking for the general hat function defined through $\varphi(x) = max\{0,1-|x|\}$ we have that $\varphi_{l_k,i_k}(x_k) = \varphi(2^{l_k}x_k-i_k))$

Comment: What regularity of the integrands do you expect to have?

Comment: The function $p$ is classically a payoff function e.g. $p(x_1,\dots,x_d) = max\{1/d \sum_{k=1}^d x_k - K, 0\}$ for a given $K>0$. Hat functions are not continously differentiable/Integrable either, therefore regularity should not be great.

Why is that important for the evaluation of the weights though? :)

Comment: If regularity is good then you can pick the weights by agreement with things like polynomials. If it isn't then you need to do something else, like ensuring that certain localized functions sgree.

Comment: Okay lets us assume I have good regularity. How do I choose my weights with polynomials then?